# Programmatically add hyperlinks to gridview for programmatically created gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically what I'm trying to do is in a loop create new gridviews and then data bind them with a set of values from a query.

```
    foreach ( var p in API.Query.GetAccoutsCustomers)
{
            var tmpatagridView = new GridView();
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tmpatagridView);
            tmpatagridView.DataSource = API.Query.GetCustomerOrders(p.CusId);
            tmpatagridView.DataBind();
}
```

the GetCustomerOrders function returns a list of objects the object is:

orderNo
cusCode
cusName
orderRef
orderVal

I want to change the order no in to a hyperlink which links to another page but I'm unsure how to do this programmatically as the GridView is created within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
foreach ( var p in API.Query.GetAccoutsCustomers)
{
            var tmpatagridView = new GridView();

            Dataset ds = API.Query.GetCustomerOrders(p.CusId);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                    HyperLinkField hplnk = new HyperLinkField();
                    hplnk.DataTextField = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                    hplnk.HeaderText = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                    tmpatagridView.Columns.Add(hplnk);
            }

            tmpatagridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            tmpatagridView.DataBind();
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tmpatagridView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are not autogenerating column. In this case instead of `orderid`, you can add following markup in the grid:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Show Detail"
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ShowEmployeeDetail.aspx?EmployeeID={0}"
     DataNavigateUrlFields="EmployeeID" />
```

Comment: but because im not creating this grid view within the aspx page im creating it programmically i don't have access to this functionality.

Comment: no you have access to the column properties. here is an example tmpatagridView.Columns.Add(boundfield); and turn off auto column generation by doing this.tmpatagridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false; add all your columns manually